# how to Show a spinner while a servlet get call gets data from server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

In the following code, i am making a servlet get request and assigning the output to a javascript variable, it takes approximately 1 minute to get the data. I would like to know how to load a spinner till the get request is complete. Please help me out.

```
var myJSONObject = null;

function getJsonData(){
$.get("getData", function(data) {
    myJSONObject = data;
});
```

Comment: `ajaxStart() and ajaxComplete` these functions could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I found the solution:

Html Code:

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
    Getting value. Please wait....<br>
    <img id="img-spinner" src="loader.gif" alt="Loading"/>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
          $(this).show();
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

where loadingDiv is your div with the spinner image.
Set loadingDiv's css as

```
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99;
  margin: auto;
}
```

And in loading div place the gif of the loader.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function getJsonData() {
    var spinner = $('<img src="spinner.gif"/>').addClass('spinner').
                      appendTo('body');
    $.get("getData", function(data) {
        myJSONObject = data;
        spinner.remove();
    });
}
```